# Error en NullPointerException

Tags: java, array, netbeans, poo

Mi programa me marca un error en el `catch`. Es un simple `JFrame` que se encarga de pedir números y evaluar que ninguno de ellos se repita, pero me marca ese error el cual no sé cómo solucionar. Agradecería si me ayudaran. Lo único que busco es un *array* que almacene los datos que vaya metiendo, pero en un `JFrame`, y que si meto uno repetido me salte el error de que ya fue registrado y de esa manera poner otro.

```
    ...         
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel etiqueta = new JLabel("Ingresa un número");
        etiqueta.setBounds(5, 5, 150, 20);
        panel.add(etiqueta);

        JTextField txtNum = new JTextField();
        txtNum.setBounds(5, 30, 150, 20);
        panel.add(txtNum);

        JButton boton = new JButton("Aceptar");
        boton.setBounds(40, 60, 80, 30);
        panel.add(boton);

        JLabel mensaje = new JLabel("");
        mensaje.setBounds(5, 100, 150, 20);
        panel.add(mensaje);

        boton.addActionListener((ActionListener) new ActionListener () {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String cedula = "";
                int i = 0, x = 0, cantidadCedulas = cedulas.length;
                boolean salir = false, existe = false;


                while(i < cantidadCedulas && salir == false) {
                    try {
                        cedula = txtNum.getText();
                        if(cedula.isEmpty()) {
                            mensaje.setText("Campo Vacio");
                        }else {
                            x = 0;
                            existe = false;
                            if(i > 0) {
                                while(x < cantidadCedulas && existe == false) {
                                    if(cedulas[x] != null && cedulas[x].equals(cedula)) {
                                        existe = true;
                                        mensaje.setText("El numero ya existe");
                                    }
                                    x++;
                                }
                            }
                            if(existe == false) {
                                cedulas[i] = cedula;
                                i++;
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        salir = true;
                    }
                }
                        }
        });

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Prueba ventana =  new Prueba();
        ventana.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Checa si esta pub. te ayuda https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados

Comment: Me temo que no podemos ayudarte, y menos sin saber donde se lanza tu `NPE`. Tendrás que depurar tu código y ver en que punto se encuentra el `null`. Revisa la publicación que te enlazo Aprendiz te ayudara a arreglar los `NPE` ya sea en este caso o en los futuros.

Comment: Cuando se produce una excepción, el mensaje del error es fundamental para saber en qué línea y por qué. En tu caso, sabrás qué método está ejecutando sobre qué objeto que tiene valor `null`. Con esa información, tú mismo averiguarías el error en segundos. Te recomiendo tracear la variable `e` que tienes en el `catch`. Si por ti mismo no lo descubres, entonces publicas el error para ayudarnos a darte una solución.